# prop classes in a reusable react component

Tags: reactjs

For you React geniuses this is going to be easy peasy. For me, learning this stuff, not so much...but I try :) Here is what I am trying to do

I am building small reusable components and I have successfully passed props to control the component properties but one that is eluding me is classes. See the component below

```
const CMLabel = ({ classes, children, ...otherProps }) => {
    return (
        <FormLabel 
            component="label" 
            {...otherProps}
            className={classes.label}>
            {children}
        </FormLabel>

    );
};
```

This can be used like this

```
<CMLabel>Hello World </CMLabel>
```

And it will render with the label class specified within the component, like this:

```
<label class="label">Hello World </label>
```

however, I want to give it more freedom as to be able to use it like this:

```
<CMLabel className="myClass">Hello World </CMLabel>
```

And it would render this way (label from the component and myClass added while using the component):

```
<label class="label myClass">Hello World </label>
```

How can I add that ability to my props so that it renders the labels class and the additional class they choose to enter? I was hoping that's how ...otherProps works but I'm not getting it to work. Do I need to cascade ...otherProps inside the `className={}`? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right path. What you're missing is merging the default className with the className(s) given via the component props. What you could do is create an array of classnames and push all the additional classnames into that array. So like this;

```
const CMLabel = (props) => {
    const classNames = [props.classes.label];
    if (props.className) {
        classNames.push(props.className);
    }
    return (
        <FormLabel 
            component="label" 
            className={classNames.join(' ')} >
            {props.children}
        </FormLabel>

    );
};
```

Comment: that almost worked. I'm not using props.className, instead I'm using {className} I can only use one method or the other. I modified it like this `if (className) {
        classNames.push({className});
    }` but in the console I am getting `class="MuiFormLabel-root-3770 CMLabel-label-3774 [object Object]"`

Comment: I swapped to props and it worked! May I modify your answer with my code for any other readers? You'll get credit anyway

Comment: Great, go ahead!